# Why there is linking error if I try to use stl vector and CUDA thrust vector in the same project?

Tags: c++, stl, cuda, thrust

Why there is linking error if I try to use stl vector and CUDA thrust vector in the same project?

File1.h

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    A();
    vector<int> vec;
//....
};
```

File2.cu

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
void ComputeDer(){
thrust::device_vector<int> Dh(4);
thrust::host_vector<int> H(4);//only host_vector can compile.
}
```

If I comment out one of the vector declaration, the code can be compiled, but if both exist, there are following errors:

```
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in ComputeDer.cu.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in ComputeDer.cu.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in ComputeDer.cu.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char const * __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEPBDXZ) already defined in ComputeDer.cu.obj
```

can anyone give me any idea ?

Comment: Can you show the linker options ? I amn't familiar with Cuda. Is `ComputeDer.cu` another source file ?

Comment: I have only  added the following two lib:cudart.lib and cuda.lib.
The others are the default setting of VS 2008

Comment: Ok. Are these debug library versions ? From the error, I understand you are building files in `Debug` configuration. So, all linking libraries needs to be debug versions. You can not mix release and debug versions of libraries.

Comment: Here is the parth:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\lib\Win32\
I compile under debug mode

Comment: That is just a path where the libraries are. The concern is that the folder has debug library versions or not. Also, try building the project in `Release` configuration and see if the problem is reproduced.

Comment: Thank you but the problem still exists in release mode.

Comment: Can you please post makefile - how the whole thing is compiled?

Comment: sorry, but I don't know how to generate makefile in VS 2008.

Comment: first of all, post complete files that can be used to try and reproduce what you are doing.  You have posted one `.cu` file and one `.h` file, and the `.h` file is not included in the `.cu` file, so it's not clear what's going on in your project. I'm not asking for all your project files.  You should be able to create a reproducer that consists of just one additional `.cpp` file that includes your `.h` file.  Keep it simple. Second, post the *complete* error output, *everything* that is displayed in the output window at the bottom of the VS display, after you launch the compille/build command.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely problem is in

```
using namespace std;
```

It is not good practice to use it at all, but if you chose to use it, at least put it into .cpp files using it but not in your header files. By putting it in header file you extrapolate it to all files including that header.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have tried "std::vector<int> vec;" in File1.h, the problem is still there.

Comment: @user3092410 Did you tried removing using namespace std; completely from all headers, or just addressing the vector as sd::vector but still having using namespace std; directive somewhere?

Comment: Thank you, but I have removed all the "using namespace std" in the entire project.It cannot solve the problem. Is there any issue with the compiler setting? Because I find it OK with other's project.